# z/OS client web enablement toolkit: Request (HWTHRQST) failing with HWTH-COMMUNICATION-ERROR (262)

Tags: rest, web, cobol, mainframe, zos

I have been using the z/OS client web enablement toolkit in a COBOL program on the mainframe successfully to call an external REST API (non-HTTPS). However, I encountered one case where the requests to the same API fail with the error `HWTH-COMMUNICATION-ERROR` (return code 262).

This is what I see in the diagnostic area:

- Request failed (HWTHRQST)
- Return code: 262 (HWTH-COMMUNICATION-ERROR)
- Service: 000524288
- Reason Code: 140
- Reason Desc: EDC5140I Broken pipe.

I'm unable to tell what is causing it to fail in only certain cases. Can anyone help me understand what the issue could be?

Here's a verbose log from the execution where it failed:

```
t: HWTH_OPT_VERBOSE has been set to HWTH_VERBOSE_ON
t-Entry: iconnImpl
t-Entry: initTranslationTables
t-Exit: initTranslationTables
t: Connecting to XX.XXX.XX.XXX via port 8080
t: Attempting to connect to IP address: XX.XXX.XX.XXX
t-Entry: setSocketOptions
t-Exit: setSocketOptions
t: Connection established using socket: 0
t-Entry: checkForTTLS
t: ATTLS detection OK: s=0 pol=OFF
t: Socket maps to TTLSRule: (none)
t: ATTLS is *not* in effect
t: Connected to origin server with socket: 0
t-Exit: iconnImpl
t: HWTH_OPT_VERBOSE has been set to HWTH_VERBOSE_ON
t-Entry: sendrqst
t-Entry: sendrqstImpl
t-Entry: appendRequestLine
t: No proxy is being used for the request
ÝHWTHCKST¨ (no request cookies specified)
ÝHWTHCKST¨ getCookieHeader() - No applicable cookies found
t: No applicable cookies found
t: * * * * * HTTP REQUEST HEADERS * * * * *
t-Entry: cleanseReqHdrs
t: GET /rest/validate/results.json
t: * * * * * END HTTP REQUEST HEADERS * * * * *
t-Entry: translate
t-Exit: translate
t-Entry: sendInlineRequest
t-Entry: doSend
t-Entry: ignoreSignal
t: Unable to query current action for signal: 13 error: EDC5157I. An internal error has occurred.
t: Unable to ignore signal(s)
t: Unresponsive socket (will attempt reconnect).
t-Entry: setReturnCode
t-Exit: setReturnCode
t: Unable to send HTTP message.
t-Entry: reconnect
t-Entry: idiscImpl
t: Closing socket: 0
t-Exit: idiscImpl
t-Entry: iconnImpl
t-Entry: initTranslationTables
t-Exit: initTranslationTables
```

Here's the verbose log from the execution where it was successful:

```
t: HWTH_OPT_VERBOSE has been set to HWTH_VERBOSE_ON
t-Entry: iconnImpl
t-Entry: initTranslationTables
t-Exit: initTranslationTables
t: Connecting to XX.XXX.XX.XXX via port 8080
t: Attempting to connect to IP address: XX.XXX.XX.XXX
t-Entry: setSocketOptions
t-Exit: setSocketOptions
t: Connection established using socket: 0
t-Entry: checkForTTLS
t: ATTLS detection OK: s=0 pol=OFF
t: Socket maps to TTLSRule: (none)
t: ATTLS is *not* in effect
t: Connected to origin server with socket: 0
t-Exit: iconnImpl
t: HWTH_OPT_VERBOSE has been set to HWTH_VERBOSE_ON
t-Entry: sendrqst
t-Entry: sendrqstImpl
t-Entry: appendRequestLine
t: No proxy is being used for the request
ÝHWTHCKST¨ (no request cookies specified)
ÝHWTHCKST¨ getCookieHeader() - No applicable cookies found
t: No applicable cookies found
t: * * * * * HTTP REQUEST HEADERS * * * * *
t-Entry: cleanseReqHdrs
t: GET /rest/validate/results.json
t: * * * * * END HTTP REQUEST HEADERS * * * * *
t-Entry: translate
t-Exit: translate
t-Entry: sendInlineRequest
t-Entry: doSend
t-Entry: ignoreSignal
t: now ignoring signal: SIGPIPE
t-Exit: ignoreSignal
t-Entry: restoreSignal
t: restoring signal: SIGPIPE
t-Exit: restoreSignal
t: send()
t:  bytes sent: 384
t:  total bytes: 384
t:  bytes remaining: 384
t: send successful.
t-Exit: doSend
t-Exit: sendrqstImpl
t-Entry: recvresp
t-Entry: recvrespImpl
t-Entry: initReceiveVars
t: Response buffer is empty.
t-Entry: getNextResponseData
t: Now processing 1547 additional response bytes.
t-Entry: processResponseData
t-Entry: translate
t-Exit: translate
t-Entry: parseResponseHeaders
t: HTTP status = 200
t: HTTP version = HTTP/1.1
t: HTTP reason = OK
t: Header: Date =
t-Entry: headerCallback
t-Exit: headerCallback
t: Header: Content-Type = application/json
t-Entry: headerCallback
t-Exit: headerCallback
```

Comment: We did run into similar issues when trying to use the toolkit in E15/E35-SORT-exits. Combining some pieces of IBM-documentation showed, that using the toolkit in a SORT-environment (Ithink it did include COBOL SORT-statements using datasets) is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=messages-edc5157i), the Programmer Response for EDC5157I (which is in the verbose log of the failing call) is "Report this problem to your system programmer."  That's IBM's way of saying "something bad happened and you probably can't fix it, but your sysprog can at least gather diagnostics to try to figure it out."

So I suggest starting with whomever is responsible for the product and supplying them with the information you've posted here along with a pointer to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I work on toolkit.  Thanks for including some context lines from your verbose trace.  Those trace outputs can get big, and you've dialed in on the right parts.

Bottom line: This looks like a "clash of the signal handlers".  This can happen when your HWTHRQST process uses a connection handle that was opened by some other process or MVS task.  Open connection handles cannot be shared between MVS tasks, and each MVS task only gets one open (connected) handle at a time.

To be fair, the problem toolkit reported to you is sort of misleading, since it "masks" this problem exposed in the verbose trace...

```
t: Unable to query current action for signal: 13 error: EDC5157I. An internal error has occurred.
t: Unable to ignore signal(s)
t: Unresponsive socket (will attempt reconnect).
```

This underlying problem is that the current task can't change the POSIX signals mask.  That means something is really goofed up.  Somebody called us from left field.  This condition has been seen before in cases where one task's connection handle is inadvertently shared with another task in the same address space.  Again, intentionally sharing an open connection between tasks is not supported.

One thing I might add...  It appears (from your verbose trace) that your z/OS system is behind on toolkit APARs and fixes. Recent fixes include a timestamped "trace prefix" on every line of verbose trace, and they can be very helpful in cases like this one.

But, getting real for a moment, unless you *are* the system programmer, applying toolkit maintenance is definitely in the "call your friendly system programmer" category ("not something you can fix yourself" -- as so eloquently put by a prior poster ;-).

Toolkit fixes at this level require an IPL with CLPA (Clear Link Pack Area), which practically defines "disruptive operation.")  As to whether this problem rises to the level of an APAR and related fix, that's beyond my pay grade.  *8-)

I sure hope this helps, and maybe even prompts a stimulating thread.  I've been a stack overflow lurker/fan for years -- it feels good to maybe have an answer for someone, for a change.

-blair